# Scala generic format convert determain

Tags: scala, localdate

Please see this function that convert `String` into `LocalDate`:

```
  def getLocalDate(date: String): LocalDate = {

    LocalDate.parse(date, format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM, yyyy"))
  }
```

Usage:

```
val date = "01 Jan, 2010"
val localDate = getLocalDate(date)
```

So in case i have date with different format:

```
val date  = "01 Jan, 2010"
```

Is it possible to enable my function to support several formats instead of support only 1 ?

Comment: There's infinite formats. How does it know your format for this string? You must pass the format in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider chaining calls to `parse` using `scala.util.Try`

```
def getLocalDate(date: String): LocalDate = {
  val pattern1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM, yyyy")
  val pattern2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
  val pattern3 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

  val result = Try {
    LocalDate.parse(date, pattern1)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern2)
  } recover {
    case _ => LocalDate.parse(date, pattern3)
  }

  result.get
}
```

`parse` throws `DateTimeParseException` when unable to parse a string. One can catch it and try again with another pattern.

After each step returned value is a Success or a Failure. In case of Success following recoveries are ignored.

Finally call `get` to return `LocalDate` contained in `Success` or rethrow exception caught by `Failure`.

Comment: What this ISO_LOCAL_DATE means inside pattern3 ?

Comment: It's meant as a example pattern. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html section "Predefined Formatters"

Comment: Can i add another formats for example yyyy-MM-dd ---> 2016-01-06 ?

Comment: DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: @davidhol has my solution resolved your problem or maybe I should clarify something more?